# static variables vs static properties

Tags: c#, properties, static

Sorry about the vague description.  I had a scenario a while back where something did not work when I used 'North' in the code below.  But when I rearranged the code and defined 'North' like 'X', it worked.  For the life of me, I cannot remember what it was (it was another class, not the one below).  If it makes any difference, Bearing is a class that simply wraps a double (N) and keeps it in the range 0 >= N < 360.
Does anyone have any thoughts on the reason for doing it in either way?  Is one better?   Why?
Thank you.

```
public struct Bearing : IComparable
{
    #region Named Bearings

    /// <summary>
    /// A bearing representing North (this is the default)
    /// </summary>
    public static Bearing North = new Bearing(0.0);

    public static Bearing X
    {
        get { return new Bearing(0.0); }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way is effectively "read-only". This way:

```
public static Bearing X
{
    get { return new Bearing(0.0); }
}
```

Returns a new `Bearing` every time you read it.

The other only has the default when its instantiated and can be changed by any part of the code. When you read from it.. it has the changed value.

So, which one is better? Whatever your use case is. They both do different things.

Comment: Thank you.  It is meant to be a 'constant', so I guess the 'X' way is the way to go.

Comment: Not really.. just mark the other way `readonly` and you have your runtime constant.

Comment: Simon, I was just about to add that option.  Thanks for your input guys.  Answered..